# website session not set

Tags: php

I'm kind of a website development nub so bear with me.

My problem is that the website php session doesn't seem to be set when I log in to my website. After ensuring that the username and password are correct, I have the following simple code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword;
```

Content that should display after logging in is not displayed.

For example:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
echo "<a class=\"logout\" href=\"logout.php\"><img      src=\"Images\logout_button.png\"></a>";
} 
else{
echo "<a class=\"login\" href=\"main_login.php\"><img src=\"Images\login_button.png\"></a>";
}
```

The login button is always visible.

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have `session_start()` on every page that needs the session variables. Do you have `session_start()` on the page with the login/logout links?

Comment: Aha! That, along with Olafur's answer, fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start the session before you set the session variables. `session_start()` should be the first thing that runs.

Comment: moved session_start() to beginning

Answer (score -2):

Per [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) `session_start()` must be before the HTML div.

Comment: If that is really what W3Schools says, there's another reason never to use it. "Before the HTML div"? Really? Also, though; did you see the existing answers, already accepted? The problem was a completely lack of `session_start()` at all. Not its misplacement.

Comment: The location of the "HTML div" (what?) has absolutely no bearing on the behavior of `session_start()`.